# How can I translate ES6 template tag in normal jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript

I used this code in a tabbed map (two maps in tabs).

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#lefttab').click(function(e) {
           $(window).on("hashchange", function(){
        var hash = this.location.hash;
        var mytab = $(hash + "-tab");
    });
        $('.tabs .nav-item a').removeClass('active');
        $('.tabs .tab').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#tab1-tab').addClass('active');
    })
    $('#righttab').click(function(e) {

       $(window).on("hashchange", function(){
        var hash = this.location.hash;
        var mytab = $(hash + "-tab");
    }); 
        $('.tabs .nav-item a').removeClass('active');
        $('.tabs .tab').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
       $('#tab2-tab').addClass('active');
    })

    function onHashChange() {    
        var hash = window.location.hash;    
        if (hash) {
            // using ES6 template string syntax
            $(`[data-toggle="tab"][href="${hash}"]`).trigger('click');
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', onHashChange, false);
    onHashChange();

});
```

My goal was to be able to open different tabs based on hash, from an external url.

This part : ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518237/how-to-open-a-tab-from-external-link/48520606))

```
function onHashChange() {    
        var hash = window.location.hash;    
        if (hash) {
            // using ES6 template string syntax
            $(`[data-toggle="tab"][href="${hash}"]`).trigger('click');
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', onHashChange, false);
    onHashChange();
```

..is using ES6 and my map doen't work anymore on IE..

can someone help me translate this in normal javascript to make it work in all browsers ?

Comment: Just paste it into an online transpiler

Comment: You already now the name of the feature. Grab a tutorial, read how they work and then just replace them with their non-ES6 counterpart... -> [Template literals (Template strings) - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: You can use babel for convert from es6 in this page, use es2015 checkbox: https://babeljs.io/repl

Comment: All there is to do is change `\`[href="${hash}"]\`` into `'[href="' + hash + '"]'`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go,

```js
$('[data-toggle="tab"][href="'+ hash + '"]').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Yes thank you all ! I found it just before you answered !! Thanks